How to get elements from array with Jolt Transform and make new attributes with their values in NiFi
I have a JSON:
{
  "FILE": "23, 21, 24, 25"
}

I need it to look like this:
[
  {
    "FILE": {
      "First": "23",
      "Second": "21",
      "Third": "24",
      "Fourth": "25"
    }
  }
]

I made an array first with jolt transformation:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "FILE": "=split(',',@(1,FILE))"
    }
  }
]

So now I have:
{
  "FILE": [
    "23",
    "21",
    "24",
    "25"
  ]
}

How can I get elements from this array and make new attributes with them? Is there any way to get them by index maybe?

How are you going to define the attribue first , second, third....? Based on what and what is the limit?

There's no converter function to determine literal ordinals, but suffixes (st,nd,rd,th) along with incremented numerical indexes might be presented through the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split(', ',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {//generate values vs. keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2.v_&",
          "$": "&2.k_&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//increment keys by one
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "k_*": "=intSum(1,@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "k_*|v_*": "&1.&(0,1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0": "&2.@(1,[1])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
,
  { // add ordinal suffixes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "1|*1": {
          "@": "&2.&st"
        },
        "2|*2": {
          "@": "&2.&nd"
        },
        "3|*3": {
          "@": "&2.&rd"
        },
        "*|11|12|13": {
          "@": "&2.&th"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

which will result for a JSON input of :
{
  "FILE" : {
    "1st" : "23",
    "2nd" : "21",
    "3rd" : "24",
    "4th" : "25",
    "5th" : "29",
    "6th" : "32"
  }
}

for the input
{
  "FILE": "23, 21, 24, 25, 29, 32"
}


@Pauline Rumyantseva Please don't forget to upvote also, simce only upvoting increases the score for the tag badges, thanks in advance.
